# Ajax submit multiple forms using a single forms' values

Tags: php, ajax, forms, jquery

So lets say I have some forms like this:

Form A:

```
<form name="formA">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="text" name="password">
</form>
```

Form B:

```
<div style="display:none;">
  <form name="formB">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="password">
  </form>
</div>
```

Form C:

```
<div style="display:none;">
 <form name="formC">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="password">
 </form>
</div>
```

Forms B and C are hidden, I have them there because after a user enters their username and password in form A, I need to also use that username and password information they submitted to be used in forms B and C, and then submit all forms at once. This is so I can submit a login to multiple parts of my website using just 1 login form. How exactly should I go about doing this?

-Thanks!

Comment: first of all change the input type **text => password** for field password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need https for login function, you can try this using jQuery and [ajaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin:

```
<form name="formA" action="actionA">
  <input id="usernameA" type="text" name="username">
  <input id="passwordA" type="password" name="password">
</form>

<div style="display:none;">
  <form name="formB" action="actionB">
    <input id="usernameB" type="text" name="username">
    <input id="passwordB" type="password" name="password">
  </form>
</div>

<div style="display:none;">
  <form name="formC" action="actionC">
    <input id="usernameC" type="text" name="username">
    <input id="passwordC" type="password" name="password">
  </form>
</div>


$('#formA').submit(function() {
    var username = $('#usernameA').val();
    var password = $('#passwordA').val();

    $('#usernameB').val(username);
    $('#passwordB').val(password);
    $('#usernameC').val(username);
    $('#passwordC').val(password);

    $('#formB').ajaxForm(function() { 
        alert("You have been logged in at B"); 
    });
    $('#formC').ajaxForm(function() { 
        alert("You have been logged in at C"); 
    }); 
});
```

When you send an ajax request to the server for login at B and C, if your server send back a cookie on successful login, I think you're good to go :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple values for each variable name. For example:

```
<form name="formABC">
  <div id="formA">
    <input type="text" name="username[]">
    <input type="text" name="password[]">
  </div>
  <div id="formB" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="username[]">
    <input type="text" name="password[]">
  </div>
  <div id="formC" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="username[]">
    <input type="text" name="password[]">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should be using `type="password"` for password input fields.

2) You cannot submit more than one form at a time. Only the data from the form that is being submitted will be sent. From what I understand that you're trying to do, you want one button to open three different pages to three different login forms to store three different sessions. There are better ways to make your sessions (or cookies) work across multiple sections of your website, such as attaching the session ID to the URL so you always have it for every page load.

3) A form needs to have an `action` defined.

Comment: Thanks, I realize i didnt put type="password" in there, or an action for the forms; it was just an example. Is there somewhere i can go to where i can learn about attaching cookie/session IDs to the url?

Comment: @MJ93: [passing session id via url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827910/passing-session-id-via-url) - However, I recommend actually adding the ID to the URL yourself when moving between the different sections of your website, rather than using those PHP settings.