# login authentication on disabled cookies in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies

How to continue the session id if cookies is disabled on clients browser?

we can continue in core as `session_id($_GET['session_id'])`. But how can we do in `Codeigniter`?

Answer (score 0):

If the cookies are not enabled then you can go by the GET and POST parameters, but they are hardly recommended.

In the session class of codeigniter the value of the session id is encrypted and then store in the cookies. using session id directly by GET and POST you will be opening doors to session fixation using ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true).

In codeigniter also you can pass the value in the same manner either add in the url as a parameter. /controller/method/parameter

go through the below articles:-

[Codeigniter's session data, are they just cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943145/codeigniters-session-data-are-they-just-cookies)

http://jctweb.net/2011/09/20/sessions-without-cookies-in-codeigniter/