# PHP opens 2nd session unwanted

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

Requirement: use QRBOT-app to scan a barcode on a mobile and give the number scanned to the website.
Problem: I've a session open (1), from here I'm opening the app (see ScanBardcode.php), I scan and the app returns to the callback-URL including the required parameters. However I do expect it is re-using it's session, it creates a new one (2). Can someone help me? It does have both sessions active and both pages keep using it's own session. I can only test it on my cell phone, which I checked is using each time (the initiate-1 and the callback-2 the same browser)
What I tried already:
1. Pass the sessionID in the callback URL (QRBOT doesn't allow parameters)
2. Set Session.auto_start to 1

**ScanBarcode.php**

```
<?php
   include_once('../../config.inc.php'); //contains DB connection details and other settings
   include_once($fullurl . '../../admin/includes/sessie.inc.php'); //generates session
    echo "SessionID=". session_id() . "!";
    $_SESSION['BarCode'] = "VoorraadTellen";
    echo "Wat gaan we doen? " . $_SESSION['BarCode'] . "</br></br>";
  //URL to open qrbot.
    echo "<a href=https://qrbot.net/x-callback-url/scan?x-success=https%3A%2F%2Filonashairstyling.nl/2016UAT/module/Ilonas_admin/ScanBarcodeCallBack.php?".">click</a>"
?>
```

**ScanBarcodeCallBack.php**

```
    <?php
     $source = $_GET['x-source'];
     $content = $_GET['content'];
     $format = $_GET['format'];
     include_once('../../config.inc.php');
     include_once($fullurl . '../../admin/includes/sessie.inc.php'); 
     echo "Wat gaan we doen? " . $_SESSION['BarCode'] . "</br></br>";
     echo "SessionID=". session_id() . "!";
     echo $source . $content . $format;

  // HERE I WRITE TO THE DB.
    ?>
```

**sessie.inc.php**

```
<?php
$a = session_id();
if(empty($a)) 
    {
        session_start();
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['sgebruiker'])) 
    {
        $now = time();
        if($now - $_SESSION['stijd'] > $_SESSION['maxidle']) 
        {
            $_SESSION = array();
            session_destroy();
        } 
        else 
        {
            $_SESSION['stijd'] = $now;
        }
    } 
    elseif(isset($_COOKIE['login_cookie'])) 
        {
            //Check against db and set cookie.
        }
?>
```

Adding screenshot when I add the sessionId in the URL as a parameter:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rABf.jpg)

**Update to ScanBarcode.php**

```
`echo "<a href=https://qrbot.net/x-callback-url/scan?x-success=https%3A%2F%2Filonashairstyling.nl/2016UAT/module/Ilonas_admin`/ScanBarcodeCallBack.php?s=".htmlspecialchars(session_id()).">click</a>"
```

Comment: Sessions are tied to a specific application. The browser and the QRBOT application each have their own session cookie.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your reply. Do you have any recommendation how to overcome this issue?

Comment: I think passing the session ID as a URL parameter should work. Show how you tried to do that. Here's the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)

Comment: @Barmar I've updated the URL in Barcode.php to      echo "<a href=https://qrbot.net/x-callback-url/scan?x-success=https%3A%2F%2Filonashairstyling.nl/2016UAT/module/Ilonas_admin/ScanBarcodeCallBack.php?s=".htmlspecialchars(session_id()).">click</a>". When I run a testI get an error in the app (it looks like it is trying to add parameters twice)

Comment: Put the code in the question so it will be formatted properly.

Comment: Do you really have backticks in the code?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know you don't need the whole check with `session_id()`. PHP Documentation for `session_start()` says:

> session_start() creates a session **or resumes the current one** based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

this is also my experience. every time i used `session_start()` i just put it at the top of every file (or included it like you did)

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I did comment out some of the session-file and put the session_start() function without the check - it is indeed existing session if open, however it didn't resolve the problem I've.

Comment: i'm sorry. i think i misunderstood the problem.

Comment: have you tried to add the session id to the callback URL like this:
echo '<a href="...qrbot.net/.../scan?x-success=' . urlencode('<your url including ?s=sessionid>') . '">';

Comment: That solved the problem - I will clean up the code and post it as an answer. @Tsia

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the session ID in the URL, you need to use the parameter to set the session ID before calling `session_start()`. Change `sessie.inc.php` to:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['s'])) {
    session_id($_GET['s']);
}
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['sgebruiker'])) 
{
    $now = time();
    if($now - $_SESSION['stijd'] > $_SESSION['maxidle']) 
    {
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $_SESSION['stijd'] = $now;
    }
} 
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['login_cookie'])) 
{
    //Check against db and set cookie.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with both @Tsai and @Barmar we found the solution.
We fixed it by:
 - Encoding the URL by using urlencode-function
 - Take the sessionID from URL and apply that using session_id-function before initiating the start_session ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827910/passing-session-id-via-url)).

The cleaned up code below; hopefully someone would be able to use it also.

**ScanBarcode.php**

```
<?php
   include_once('../../config.inc.php'); //contains DB connection details and other settings
   include_once($fullurl . '../../admin/includes/sessie.inc.php'); //generates session
    echo "SessionID=". session_id();
  //URL to open qrbot.
$CallbackUrl = "http://ilonashairstyling.nl/2016UAT/module/Ilonas_admin/ScanBarcodeCallBack.php?s=" . htmlspecialchars(session_id());
echo "<a href=https://qrbot.net/x-callback-url/scan?x-success=". urlencode($CallbackUrl) . ">click</a>"
?>
```

**ScanBarcodeCallBack.php**

```
<?php
  $source = $_GET['x-source'];
  $content = $_GET['content'];
  $format = $_GET['format'];

  include_once('../../config.inc.php');

  ini_set("session.use_cookies",0);
  ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);
  session_id($_GET['s']);
  //print_r($_SESSION); //You can test it with this code
  //print(session_id()); //You can test it with this code

  ini_set("session.use_cookies",1);
  ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",0);

  include_once($fullurl . '../../admin/includes/sessie.inc.php'); 

  echo "Wat gaan we doen? " . $_SESSION['BarCode'] . "</br></br>";
  echo "SessionID=". session_id() . "!";
  echo $source . $content . $format;

  // HERE I WRITE TO THE DB.
?>
```

sessie.inc.php is unchanged